# Jquery Ajax call to receive binary stream

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to receive a two dimension array(key-value pair) from server, using ajax call. one of the entry is a image(binary stream blob from database,it can be png/jpeg etc). my current ajax call is able to receive the array and convert to JSON, If the image entry is absent. But i am receiving a blank array if image is added.
My code looks like this 
  this.lastRefreshAt = new Date();

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',      
        data : {
            view      : JSON.stringify(this.view),
            hours     : this.hours,
            start     : this.startTime,
            end       : this.endTime
        },

        url : 'https://' + this.baseURL() + 'data/json/incidents',
        success : function(data) {
            appl.incidents.clear();
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.success && data.success == true && data.data) {
                for(key in data.data) {
                    appl.incidents.set(parseInt(data.data[key].id), data.data[key]);
                }
enter code here
```

and data i am receiving from php server is

```
array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["data"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(17) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(5480)
      ["sys_datetime"]=>
      string(22) "01/22/2018 06:37:36 PM"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(2) "41"
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "01/22/2018"
      ["time"]=>
      string(8) "06:37 PM"
      ["title"]=>
      string(2) "we"
      ["loc_type"]=>
      string(1) "O"
      ["location"]=>
      NULL
      ["priority"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["description"]=>
      string(2) "we"
      ["detail_date"]=>
      string(10) "01/22/2018"
      ["detail_time"]=>
      string(8) "06:37 PM"
      ["desk"]=>
      int(106)
      ["contacts"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["email_recipients"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["details"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["attachment"]=>
      string(11041) "�PNG


IHDR�����tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<fiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:97B8E55B506DE511BE28A2EE00A0604A" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:0C8029AA6D5A11E5BE80C2D4D01B8CF1" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:0C8029A96D5A11E5BE80C2D4D01B8CF1" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:98B8E55B506DE511BE28A2EE00A0604A" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:97B8E55B506DE511BE28A2EE00A0604A"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>(��'QIDATx��} t\ՙ�_�T�*-�͒eaK��Ƌ�v�,2�IȘ�
�g�daΜ��i��ӧ�N��twN�b'3����I�@3i&6`����M�*[��}�}���>����^UI�������)�zU�޽���r��_[,��<�����`�0L�I�`0i���`�0L�I�`0i���`�0L�I�`0i&
��`�0L�I�`0i�\���_�j��ڻe!�,�T��)�)�P|f%,�[!�(��9J������#M����!KQ�Ԥ�=�qߩ�v��(Ҙ��]��1+|(w��GY+4J�Q#d��o�����Fye���Ic��u���(y&�ǅB���-�.a�180� blB�7��_��3)a��:q��3г�s����
ԣ|�a�g;\(�PP��(?z-
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used base64_encode() on php server before transmitting and informed Javascript on client side regarding base64 encoding.